# How to run xargs in the background?

Tags: bash, zsh

I have created an alias to search a certain directory for pdf files and open it via `xdg-open`. The problem is it doesn't run in the background.

Here's my alias:

```
 fd . ~/Documents/books -e pdf | fzf | (xargs -I % xdg-open %) &
```

Answer (score 0):

Your intent is to have an alias in the terminal that, with a single command, allows to find a PDF using fuzzy finder and open a PDF (using `xdg-open`), while having the terminal available again for the next command. Normally, the terminal is released only when you close the PDF.

You can have the graphical (or other) application that is launched by `xdg-open` using `nohup` as in

```
fdfind . Documents -e pdf | fzf | xargs -I % nohup xdg-open % 2>/dev/null
```

The output of `nohup` is redirected to `/dev/null` to avoid its message from being displayed.

As you see, it is not necessarily required to run `xargs` in the background, although you can if you wish - it will also work.

Comment: Thanks, I learned something from this. I wish there was still a standard way to run in the background any processes that open something in a UI app.

Comment: What is a standard way for you? The `nohup` command serves exactly that purpose. If this answer resolved your question, then please show your appreciation by "accepting" it: click the checkmark next to the question.